# CTE executing multiple times

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, common-table-expression

I have this structure:

```
WITH my_cte
    AS
    (
    SELECT y.name
    FROM 
        WHData.dbo.vw_data x
        INNER JOIN WHData.dbo.vw_DimNames y
                ON x.nameKey = y.CasinoKey
    WHERE DateKey >= CONVERT(CHAR(8),DATEADD(mm,-2,GETDATE() - DAY(GETDATE())) + 1,112)--two complete months ago    
    GROUP BY y.name
    )
SELECT *
FROM    WHAnalysis.dbo.tb_otherData a
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
                (
            SELECT 1
            FROM my_cte b
            WHERE b.name = a.name 
            );
```

If I run the code in the `CTE` in isolation it takes 3 secs; but the complete script just runs and runs.

If I move away from a `CTE` and use an indexed temporary table then it all runs in 4secs.

What I assume is happening is that the `CTE` is executing against each record of data in `tb_otherData` so it'll probably take, as there are 2000 records, 2000 x 3sec ....too long!

The temp table solution is fine but, out of interest, is there a way to change the `CTE` code so that it runs quickly? Are there some `CTE` tricks that I am missing?

---

**EDIT**

If I switch to a good old fashioned sub-query then the execution plan is absolutely identical:

```
SELECT *
FROM   WHAnalysis.dbo.tb_otherData a
WHERE name not in 
        (
            SELECT y.name
            FROM 
            WHData.dbo.vw_data x
            INNER JOIN WHData.dbo.vw_DimNames y
            ON x.nameKey = y.CasinoKey
             WHERE DateKey >= CONVERT(CHAR(8),DATEADD(mm,-2,GETDATE() - DAY(GETDATE())) + 1,112)--two complete months ago   
              GROUP BY y.name
              );
```

Comment: CTEs are just syntactic sugar in this case - they make you think they are only evaluating once but that is often not the case. Are you looking for an explanation or a workaround (e.g. writing the query without a CTE *and* without a temp table)?

Comment: @AaronBertrand actually I've just tested and the execution plan is **EXACTLY** the same if I switch to a sub-query. I was actually wondering if I could keep the CTE but maybe there was a trick I was missing to make it faster? p.s. got into a slightly heated discussion with a_horse_with_no_name the other day who told me I should alias columns like `x as mycolumn` but also mentioned your name - I thought you were of the school `mycolumn = x` ?

Comment: Yes, a CTE is just a different way to write a sub query. If we're not talking recursive they will likely optimize identically. And yes I'm `alias = column` but it's just a preference and not worth arguing over. I'll argue against people using `column as 'alias'` OR `'alias' = column`, but only to get rid of the stupid string delimiters that are confusing and deprecated.

Comment: https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2012/01/23/bad-habits-to-kick-using-as-instead-of-for-column-aliases.aspx

Comment: Is `DateKey` from `WHData.dbo.vw_data` or `WHData.dbo.vw_DimNames`?

Comment: @valex it is from `vw_data`

Comment: @AaronBertrand what are the "stupid string delimiters that are confusing and deprecated" ?

Comment: `'alias'` looks like a string. `alias` does not. I wasn't saying you we're doing that, I just think it's a much stronger argument against certain alias syntax than worrying about = vs. AS

Comment: @AaronBertrand I don't use `[]` or `''` around my aliases unless it has a gap or if it clashes with a sql word then I use square brackets: so I'd have `[my column name]` or I'd have `[Date]` or `myColumn`. Is this ok ? Problem is that there doesn't seem to be a definitive way ....why don't they make SSMS more like VS when I'm writing VB.NET or C# so that the editor formats and tab the code for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use this query instead of using subquery with EXISTS:

```
SELECT a. *
FROM    WHAnalysis.dbo.tb_otherData a
LEFT JOIN
(   SELECT y.name as name
    FROM WHData.dbo.vw_data x
         INNER JOIN WHData.dbo.vw_DimNames y
                ON x.nameKey = y.CasinoKey
         WHERE DateKey >= 
          CONVERT(CHAR(8),DATEADD(mm,-2,GETDATE() - DAY(GETDATE())) + 1,112)    
) b on a.name=b.name
WHERE b.name is null
```

If `DateKey` is from `WHData.dbo.vw_data` then it will be:

```
SELECT a. *
FROM    WHAnalysis.dbo.tb_otherData a
LEFT JOIN WHData.dbo.vw_DimNames y on a.name=y.name
LEFT JOIN WHData.dbo.vw_data x
   on y.CasinoKey= x.nameKey 
      and (
          x.DateKey >= 
          CONVERT(CHAR(8),DATEADD(mm,-2,GETDATE() - DAY(GETDATE())) + 1,112)
          )
WHERE x.nameKey is null
```

Comment: +1 this L.O.J is spot on; for some reason it is much faster - the execution plan when using a LOJ has no nested loops in it; maybe that is the gain.

Comment: If it is possible you should avoid nested subqueries and `IN` subqueries using JOINs instead.

Comment: @valex why? In a lot of cases, EXISTS / NOT EXISTS performs better than JOINs (and for inner joins and non-nullable columns, IN/EXISTS can produce the exact same plan). [Here's a blog post I wrote on NOT EXISTS](http://sqlperformance.com/left-anti-semi-join). But you should always test rather than make sweeping generalizations.